# Optimizing SQL query with sub queries

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have got a SQL query that I tried to optimize and I could reduce through various means the time from over 5 seconds to about 1.3 seconds, but no further. I was wondering if anyone would be able to suggest further improvements.

The Explain diagram shows a full scan:
[explain diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpZt9.png)

The Explain table will give you more details:
[explain tabular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsSmg.png)

The query is simplified and shown below - just for reference, I'm using MySQL 5.6

```
select * from (
  select 
    @row_num := if(@yacht_id = yacht_id and @charter_type = charter_type and @start_base_id = start_base_id and @end_base_id = end_base_id, @row_num +1, 1) as row_number,
    @yacht_id := yacht_id as yacht_id, 
    @charter_type := charter_type as charter_type,
    @start_base_id := start_base_id as start_base_id,
    @end_base_id := end_base_id as end_base_id,
    model, offer_type, instant, rating, reviews, loa, berths, cabins, currency, list_price, list_price_per_day, 
    discount, client_price, client_price_per_day, days, date_from, date_to, start_base_city, end_base_city, start_base_country, end_base_country, 
    service_binary, product_id, ext_yacht_id, main_image_url
  from (
    select
      offer.yacht_id, offer.charter_type, yacht.model, offer.offer_type, offer.instant, yacht.rating, yacht.reviews, yacht.loa, 
      yacht.berths, yacht.cabins, offer.currency, offer.list_price, offer.list_price_per_day, 
      offer.discount, offer.client_price, offer.client_price_per_day, offer.days, date_from, date_to,
      offer.start_base_city, offer.end_base_city, offer.start_base_country, offer.end_base_country,
      offer.service_binary, offer.product_id, offer.start_base_id, offer.end_base_id,
      yacht.ext_yacht_id, yacht.main_image_url
    from website_offer as offer
    join website_yacht as yacht
      on offer.yacht_id = yacht.yacht_id, 
    (select @yacht_id:='') as init
    where date_from > CURDATE() 
      and date_to <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 MONTH
      and days = 7
    order by offer.yacht_id, charter_type, start_base_id, end_base_id, list_price_per_day asc, discount desc
  ) as filtered_offers
) as offers
where row_number=1;
```

Thanks,
goppi

```
UPDATE
```

I had to abandon some performance improvements and replaced the original select with the new one. The select query is actually dynamically built by the backend based on which filter criteria are set. As such the where clause of the most inner select can expland quite a lot. However, this is the default select if no filter is set and is the version that takes significantly longer than 1 sec.

explain in text form - doesn't come out pretty as I couldn't figure out how to format a table, but here it is:

1   PRIMARY   ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 9   const   10
2   DERIVED   ALL                 385967
3   DERIVED   system                  1   Using filesort
3   DERIVED offer   ref idx_yachtid,idx_search,idx_dates    idx_dates   5   const   385967  Using index condition; Using where
3   DERIVED yacht   eq_ref  PRIMARY,id_UNIQUE   PRIMARY 4   yachtcharter.offer.yacht_id 1
4   DERIVED                             No tables used

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: please show the output of `show create table website_offer` and `show create table website_yacht` and `explain select ....rest of your query` _as text, not an image_

Comment: how long does the innermost select (`select * from website_offer ... limit 5000`) take?   what is the reason for the `limit 5000`?

Comment: By the way, avoid using variables in MySQL. They are obsolete in MySQL 8.x.

Comment: Definitely need to see the table defs as text as @ysth suggested. One thing that sticks out is that you are defeating any indexes that might exist on `date_from` or `date_to` in your `website_offer` subquery by applying a function (`date`) on those columns. You should rewrite both of those in a way that avoids that if possible. The right approach depends on the type of those columns. An answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64072215/10682164) steps in that direction, but you should do it for `date_to` as well.

Comment: @GMB - I'm using MySQL5.6 as mentioned in the original post.- Auror MySQL to be specific.

Comment: @ysth - see updated post with the additional information.Further, the inner most select takes in the new form 1.6 secs - the overall qery takes now 3.3 secs. The reason for the limit was to speed it up - even with taking only the first row of each group, i got over 400 records which would be enough. Problem is though that if other filters are set, the 5000 could result in a lower number of records and perhaps too low number. I took the limit therefor out for now and the strange thing is that now the yacht_id index is used whereas in more or less the same original query it wasnt' used.

Comment: @The Impaler: I'm aware of that variables aren't used in MySQL 8.0. I'm not sure though you actually realized why I use variables - that is becaus eMySQL 5.6 doesn't offer the same functionality as 8.0 and using variables is the best way to work around this.

Comment: Have you timed the subqueries individually? Have you tried removing parts of the query to see which has the biggest impact on performance?

Comment: @totalhack - yes, i have, the most inner query takes 1.7, the second level takes 2.4 and the full 3.2secs. The websote_offers table has close to one million records, the website_yachts table only about 7000.

Comment: @totalhack - That said, the main time in the most inner query is taken up by the sorting. The sorting is unfortunately necessary to make the grouping and picking the record of each group that has the lowest list price possible. I tried to add and force a few different indexes that have the sorting fields also included, but none is faster than using idx_dates.I did not find any particular part in the middle query that adds a lot of time. The setting of the variables takes like 0.015secs longer than without.In the outter select, picking the records with row_number = 1 takes an additional 0.6secs

Answer (score 1):

Sub selects are never great,
You should sign up here:  https://www.eversql.com/

Run that and it will give you all the right indexes and optimsiations you need for this query.

Comment: sometimes subselects are the best thing to do, sometimes they are awful, sometimes they are just equivalent to a join.  there is no general rule.

Comment: @MrPHP - eversql didn't perform well in this case. It suggested to add an index in website_offers for (`days`,`yacht_id`,`date_from`) which did get used instead of idx_dates, however with the consequence that nokey was used for website_yachts and the performance dropped from 3.3secs to 4.5 secs.

Answer (score 0):

There's still some optimization you can use. Considering the subquery returns 5000 rows only you could use an index for it.

First rephrase the predicate as:

```
select *
from website_offer
where date_from >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY -- rephrased here
  and date(date_to) <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 MONTH
  and days = 7
order by yacht_id, charter_type, list_price_per_day asc, discount desc
limit 5000
```

Then, if you add the following index the performance could improve:

```
create index ix1 on website_offer (days, date_from, date_to);
```

Comment: You should rephrase the `date_to` predicate as well if you want to take full advantage of the new index I think.

Comment: and presumably date_from is always on or before date_to, so the date_to condition could also be used for date_from and vice versa

Comment: @totalhack - Yes, rephrase `date_to` also.  But it won't help unless you also add `INDEX(days, date_to, date_from)`.  That will give the Optimizer two approaches to try -- it may find that testing `date_to` will be faster.  The Optimizer will not use both `date_from` and `date_to` except via "ICP".

Comment: @The Impaler - taking out the date() function didn't make any difference to the performance. It didn't seem to make a difference to the use of the index either. The index idx_dates includes date_from, date_to and days and was used with the date() function and without.

Comment: @Rick James that's interesting, I assumed it could have taken advantage of the full (days, date_from, date_to) index with the predicates fixed. Is there a particular reason the optimizer wouldn't be able to use the full multi part index? Any docs you can point me to explaining that? Thanks.

Comment: @totalhack - There are some discussions and links [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .  `EXPLAIN` fails to show whether the second column (tested as a "range") is effectively used.  Try `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` and the Optimizer Trace.